# Implement a PHP function that returns a HTTP status code

Tags: php, server-side

I have this question for homework and i was if i am on the right track?

Implement   a   PHP function    that    returns a   HTTP    status  code    along   with    a   custom  message in
the header  and body    of  the response    to  the client. This    function    will    be  needed  for all 
subsequent  sections,   and should  be  used    when    an  error   occurs  (invalid    input,  wrong   request 
type    etc.).

The function    must    set the appropriate HTTP    header  AND provide the message in  the 
response    body    in  JSON    format.

So far i have:

```
    function send_error($code, $message){
        echo: "Error:" 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you, but you need to look at [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Thanks i'm just looking for direction

Comment: use: `http_response_code($code);` before the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, however, to better do your homework, you have to understand that PHP comes with functions that can help you do what you need.

for example:

Function `http_response_code` will help you set the response code.

Function `json_encode` will help you convert array to json string.

Have a look at them and you should be able to do your homework.

Comment: Can json_encode be used inside the fuction? Everything im reading points to arrays/variables.

Comment: Yes, you definitely can, the simple use for it will be as follows:
`$arr = array('item1'=>1,'item2'=>2); $json = json_encode($arr);`

Comment: `http_response_code()` did not exist until PHP/5.4. For that reason you'll often see `header()` used for the same purpose ([example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#114996)).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, true, that's why the minimum PHP version to be used these days is 5.6,

Comment: Using header() instead of http_response_code(). Does header(http/1.0) mean code 100?

Comment: no @Madi, it is the protocol version, not the status code.

Comment: @Madi Nope, that's just the protocol. Full line should read "protocol code message". But of course you now have a better function: `http_response_code()`. Setting the status code with `header()` can be tricky.